# Run two animations on object in Unity simultaneously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm still pretty fresh to the Unity 3D world. I'm trying to get an animation on two children of an object (a door that has the exterior facing outward and a door facing inward). Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way? See below:

[image]

Is there a way in which by pressing one key,i can get both "open" animations for both the inward and outward facing doors to play at the same time? Note: I originally created this FBX in Blender.

Comment: Don't use Animation anymore it's legacy. Use either layers in the Animator or a Timeline

Comment: @derHugo I noticed how I can add layers on an animator, but how exactly would I call on that in code? Again, I'm wanting to run both open animations simultaneously after pressing a key... You can point me to a working example if you want

Comment: [Animation Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationLayers.html) and [Timeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TimelineSection.html) are good start points including examples of how to use them. Once you are all set up you can either use `Animator.SetTrigger("triggerName")` to start a transition or directly use [Animator.Play("StateName")](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.Play.html) to go to a certain state

Comment: @derHugo trying to play around with the Animation Layer more, what frustrates me is the model appears to import inside door in the open position by default, only to open it further??? I tried setting the location, rotation and scale for the interior door in Blender, but it appeared to make no difference when I re-imported the model...

Comment: Well, that really depends on your animation clips and setup ... simple animations like a door you should create in Unity directly ..